# FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged not working for offline?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my iOS app I have use firebase `observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged` to get realtime updates for particular node. However while user goes to offline the node update several times. But when user comes to online user cannot get previous updates. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Realtime Database synchronizes state. It does (explicitly) not synchronize all intermediate state changes.

If there were multiple changes to the same node while your client was offline, it will actually only see the final state.

```
Client1              Database               Client2
                                            Start listener
write 1     -->         1           -->        1
write 2     -->         2           -->        2
                                            Go offline
write 3     -->         3                      
write 4     -->         4                      
                                            Go online
                                    -->        4
write 5     -->         5           -->        5
```

So in the above diagram, client 2 will only see values 1, 2 and 5. It **may** see value 4 too, depending on precisely when value 5 is written. But it will definitely not see value 3.

If you want each state change to be communicated to client 2 when it reconnects, you should store the exact state changes in your database. So instead of storing the resulting value, you would store the operation. Something like:

```
Changes: {
  "-PushId1": { value: 1  },
  "-PushId2": { value: 2  },
  "-PushId3": { value: 3  },
  "-PushId4": { value: 4  },
  "-PushId5": { value: 5  }
}
```

Now if your client listens to `/Changes`, it is guaranteed to see all the changes that happened.

Comment: Yes got it. However while user was offline it has been added several new child nodes. Then user reconnects, not receives changes for `observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged`. But changes receives for `FIRDataEventTypeValue` and `FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded` without happen any changes after reconnect.